# Can we use access token or refresh token as a session id for WebService Callout?

Tags: webservices, session, apex-webservice, authorization

[there it is mentioned](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en#send_up_response)

I want to use `sessionID` for [MetadataService](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) call from an org to other org. I have the other org `access token` and `refresh token` both.

I tried to use `access token`, but got the error `Line: 10248, Column: 1 System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key:`

Answer (score 0):

Access Token == session id.

And Access token or session id will expire after certain time.
And Refresh token helps to get new Access Token(Session ID), once it expires.

Comment: its not working.
`Line: 10248, Column: 1
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: `